# Modify Makefile to simplify framework #include path

Tags: c++, makefile, frameworks, g++, cross-platform

#### Question

Is there a way to modify the `INCLUDE` path for frameworks in the `Makefile` to be able to simplify `<SDL2/SDL.h>` to `<SDL.h>` as is used for Windows?

#### Background

I am attempting to edit my team's Makefile to provide cross-platform support for Mac's native form of libraries, frameworks, in addition to the existing Windows libraries, so that we can keep the code as simple as possible.

I am aware of `#ifdef __APPLE_CC__` being used to wrap Mac-specific code, but to wrap every instance of `<SDL2/SDL.h>` and `<SDL.h>` separately seems excessive.

#### Includes needed for libs in Windows:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
```

#### Includes needed for frameworks in Mac:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2_Image/SDL_image.h>
```

#### Makefile (Incomplete)

```
# Windows part

ifeq ($(OS), Windows_NT)
    DETECTED_OS = $(OS)
    CC = g++ -std=c++11
    CFLAGS = -c -IC:/mingwdev/include/SDL2
    INCLUDE = -IC:/mingwdev/include/SDL2
    LFLAGS = -LC:/mingwdev/lib -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -o $(OUT)
    LFLAGScr = -LC:/mingwdev/lib -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image

# Mac part

else ifeq ($(shell uname -s), Darwin)
    DETECTED_OS := $(shell uname -s)
    CC = g++ -std=c++11
    CFLAGS = -c -F/Library/Frameworks        # THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO MODIFY #
    INCLUDE = -F/Library/Frameworks          # THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO MODIFY #
    LFLAGS = -framework SDL2 -framework SDL2_image -framework SDL2_ttf -o $(OUT) 
    LFLAGScr = -framework SDL2 -framework SDL2_image -framework SDL2_ttf


# Final Part

all: $(OUT)  

$(OUT): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $^ $(INCLUDE) $(LFLAGS) 

obj/%.o: src/%.cpp $(DEP)
    $(CC) $< $(CFLAGS) -o $@
```

Comment: To make things as simple as possible, write two different makefiles.

Comment: I think there is some confusion - those are three parts within the same Makefile. I will edit for clarity.

Comment: If the `-F` option does what I think it does, try changing `CFLAGS = -c -F/Library/Frameworks` to `CFLAGS = -c -F/Library/Frameworks -F/Library/Frameworks/SDL2`, and a couple of the `#include <SDL2/SDL.h>` to `#include <SDL.h>`, and see if that compiles.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, but it didn’t work. Sorry.

Comment: Also, does the person who gave a -1 for the question have any feedback as to why this is a bad question?

Answer (score 1):

To use `#include <SDL.h>` as the Windows counterpart is doing, you need to provide the path to the headers within the framework with the `-I` command in addition to letting the compiler know it is using a framework with `-F`.

The two lines in the Makefile will look like this:

```
CFLAGS = -c -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers -F/Library/Frameworks/
INCLUDE = -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers -F/Library/Frameworks/
```

To inlcude a second library, like SDL_image, you would simply do:

```
CFLAGS = -c -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers  -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL2_image.framework/Headers -F/Library/Frameworks/
INCLUDE = -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL2_image.framework/Headers -F/Library/Frameworks/
```

(You're welcome, myself and the community.)